# How to style a div to be like a rocket?

Tags: html, css

I want to style an html div to be like a rocket, I mean it should represented as an oblong with a triangle edge. Just like this screenshot:-

[image]

Comment: Since I think there have already been some good answers, I just want to say the question made me chuckle.

Comment: [This tutorial](http://www.red-team-design.com/css3-breadcrumbs) look exactly like what you are looking for. Build a breadcrumb 'rocket-like' navigation in pure CSS.

Comment: you can use `display:rocket;` - this is however a CSS6 property

Comment: @ScottBartell this's exactly what I want, thank you! you can add it as an answer so I can give you the accepted answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a [tutorial](http://www.red-team-design.com/css3-breadcrumbs) that explains how to create a few variations of breadcrumb navigation in pure CSS3.

The final result looks like this:

[image: Final Product from the Tutorial]

Here's a [working demo](http://www.red-team-design.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/css3-breadcrumbs-demo.html).

Answer (score 8):

A pure CSS solution could make use of the :after pseudoselector and abusing borders to make triangles.  This site will even generate the code for you:

http://cssarrowplease.com/

Set the position to right and the size to be the height of the div.

Answer (score 4):

You actually can do triangles with pure CSS: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/C9PJ2/

Here is what you can sort of do using css, kind fo a hack of an arrow.

```
.arrow_box {
    position: relative;
    background: #2ad517;
    border: 4px solid #12f50a;
    top: 100px;
    width: 240px;
    height: 180px
}
.arrow_box:after, .arrow_box:before {
    left: 100%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.arrow_box:after {
    border-color: rgba(42, 213, 23, 0);
    border-left-color: #2ad517;
    border-width: 90px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -90px;
}
.arrow_box:before {
    border-color: rgba(18, 245, 10, 0);
    border-left-color: #12f50a;
    border-width: 96px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -96px;
}​
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/9E9uP/

something for you to start with

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:
http://jsfiddle.net/A2KzR/

HTML:

```
<div id="global">
<div id="normal" >Content</div>
<div id="triangle-right" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#triangle-right {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 50px solid transparent;
    border-left: 100px solid red;
    border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
    left: 50px;
    position: relative;    
}

#normal {
    width: 50px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    float:left;
}

#global {
     width: 800px;   
}
```

more info
http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/